# joomla access defined xml field in controller

Tags: php, xml, joomla, http-post

I would like to access a xml field in a controller. After submitting a form containing the xml-field (name="parameter", type="text"), I tried to access the value of the field inside the controller with the following approach:

```
class NameControllerconfirmation extends NameController
{
public function test(){

$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$parametername=$input->get('parameter');


$this-setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?   
option=com_name&view=confirmation&name='.parametername,false));


}
}
```

The problem is, that $parameter is always 'null'. I've studied the joomla.docs as well as existing components intensely, but meanwhile I'm getting more and more confused.

But his Approach works great, when defining the field inside html, but I can't access the field, when it is declared as xml. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing URL parameters (which are set appending ?paramname=value to the url) with component parameters (those you set in the administrator).  The latter can be retrieved like this:

```
$componentParams = &JComponentHelper::getParams('com_example');
$param = $componentParams->get('paramName', 'defaultValue');
```

You can find a near-complete guide to extension parameters here:
http://www.themepartner.com/blog/25/retrieving-plugin-module-component-and-template-parameters/

Comment: I figured out, how it works! Here is my working approach. $data = JFactory::getApplication()->input; $mydata = $data->get('jform','array',null); It is important to add 'jform'